# Typescript optional object argument craziness

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

so I am trying to make a object parameter optional, with optional props, and have a default value at the same time:

```
const myfunc = ({ stop = false }: { stop?: boolean } = { stop: false }) => {
    // do stuff with "stop"
}
```

this works fine, but notice that crazy function definition!

Any way to not repeat so much code?

Comment: If you have a default option, then it's implicitly not optional..  IOW: just get rid of the `?`

Comment: Well, really you're dealing with two things here. (1) allowing a params object with no entries, i.e. `myfunc({})` and (2) allow no params object, i.e. `myfunc()`. This leads to the verbosity.

Comment: You can replace `{ stop = false }` with just `{ stop }` when destructuring to save some space. But if your actual use case is an object with many more properties, I would not destructure and just use something like `options.stop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably write this like this:

```
interface MyFuncOptions {
  stop: boolean;
}
const myFunc = (options: Partial<MyFuncOptions> = {}) => {
  const defaultOptions: MyFuncOptions = {
    stop: false,
  };
  const finalOptions = {
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options
  }
  const { stop } = finalOptions;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While this question is really opinionated, I see a small logical improvement here, you can set the default value to an empty object:

```
const myfunc = ({ stop = false }: { stop?: boolean } = {}) => {
    // do stuff with "stop"
}
```

Anyway I agree that this is not really readable and I used to code like that for quite some time. At some point I realized that it's much more readable if you split this statement:

```
interface MyFunctionArgs {
  stop?: boolean
}

const myfunc = (myArgs: MyFunctionArgs = {}) => {
    const { stop = false } = myArgs;
    // do stuff with "stop"
}
```

All in all I would say that TypeScript gives you a lot of ways to implement the same thing, which has its up- and downsides.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather your after where if you don't supply any params, stop = false is default, if you do select some params but leave out stop, stop is also false.

This is how I would do it ->

```
const myfunc = (p: {stop?: boolean} = { stop: false }) => {
    // do stuff with "stop"
    const {stop = false} = p;
    console.log(stop);
}


myfunc({stop: false});   //stop = false
myfunc({stop: true});    //stop = true
myfunc({});              //stop = false
myfunc();                //stop = false
```

Adding extra params doesn't get any more complicated either.

```
const myfunc = (p: {stop?: boolean, start?: boolean} = 
  { stop: false, start: false }) => {
    // do stuff with "stop"
    const {stop = false, start = false} = p;
    console.log(stop, start);
}


myfunc({stop: false});              //false false
myfunc({stop: true, start: true});  //true  true
myfunc({});                         //false false
myfunc();                           //false false 
myfunc({start: true});              //false true
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have an optional property that is defaulted to something without a crazy-looking function definition, I would simply define the interface and not use destructuring, e.g.:

```
    interface Options {
      stop?: boolean;
    }
    const myfunc = (options: Options = { stop: false }) => {
      console.log('stop', options.stop);
    }
```

However, if your actual use-case is an optional boolean, I'd re-examine the design. With boolean, if it's undefined or null, it will evaluate to be falsy anyway.